# WebClient Not Working On Shared Network

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, networking, windows, ethernet-shield

I'm working on a school project, and I use **Arduino Uno** to collect some data with sensors, and then send it to an online database. The **Arduino** is connected to the Internet via an **Ethernet Shield** and an **Ethernet cable**. I connected the Ethernet cable to my **home router**, and to the **Arduino** and everything works fine, the data is colledted, and sent to the database. But when I will present the project I **won't** have an access directly to a router, so I have to connect my laptop to WiFi and connect the **Arduino** to my laptop and **share network**. When I tested this it just did't work, I changed the Wifi network properties on my **Windows 10** Laptop, to a shared network. The **Arduino** boots up and optains an **IP adress**, but when it tries to send data to the database it it doesn't work. I connected it to the **home router** again and everything worked so the problem is with the **shared network**. What is the problem? And how to solve it?

Comment: If the problem is with the shared network then you should head over to SuperUser.com - they know all about Windows and networking.  If you're getting an IP address *and a gateway address and DNS address* then the Arduino is fine. The problem is with Windows and we can't help you there.

Comment: can you reach the database server from the laptop?

Comment: @jsotola yes I can.